# How to make sure a line of code is run after another has completed?

Tags: swift, dispatch, completionhandler

I tried to make the last two lines of this code run after the ones before them but they have always run first! Please help.

```
PostAPI.getPostById(postId: self.postId) { postResponse in
        let post = postResponse
        self.posts[indexPath.row] = post
        let cellNumber = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
        self.postsTableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNumber], with: .none)
        likesButton?.tintColor = .systemPink
        likesButton?.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Looking at this, it makes me think that you may have a larger architectural issue to solve. However, it may work in the interim to wrap your last two lines in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Comment: I'm not sure if `reloadRows` is synchronous. It simply requests that the table tries to reload that specific row (which it can decide to do later). If you want something after the reload, you need to hook into the UITableView methods somehow like `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I tried DispatchQueue.main.async but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If DispatchQueue.main.async didnt work maybe you can try a function with completion

```
PostAPI.getPostById(postId: self.postId) { postResponse in
    self.reloadThenLike {
        self.likesButton?.tintColor = .systemPink
        self.likesButton?.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), 
            for: .normal)
    }
}

func reloadThenLike(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let post = postResponse
    self.posts[indexPath.row] = post
    let cellNumber = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 
        indexPath.section)
    self.postsTableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNumber], with: .none)
    completion()
}
```

Comment: Michael, what you wrote makes sense, however, it's not working! I started to think the problem is somewhere else! Let me re-write what I'm doing, I have a viewControl called Post which has a UITableView of posts, I have a class called PostCell which defines the UITableViewCell. I made a button function in PostCell called likeButtonClicked

Comment: @IBAction func likesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "likeButtonClicked"), object: nil, userInfo: ["cell":self, "likesButton":likesButton!])
    }

Comment: I subscried to the above notification in viewDidLoad in Post view controler then tried Michael code but did not work! Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reloading the table view using `CATransaction`

**1. Create a table view extension to add completion to rows reload**

```
extension UITableView
{
    func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath],
                    with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation,
                    completion: (() -> Void)?)
    {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
        reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: animation)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

**Then try adjusting your code to use it as follows**

```
PostAPI.getPostById(postId: self.postId) { postResponse in
    let post = postResponse
    self.posts[indexPath.row] = post
    let cellNumber = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
    
    // Reload the table view with completion handler
    self.postsTableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNumber], with: .none) { [weak self] in
        
        // Reload complete, do your work
        self?.likesButton?.tintColor = .systemPink
        self?.likesButton?.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
        
    }
}
```

Give this a go and see if this helps you

Comment: all the suggestions offered lead to the same result. I click once the likes increases by 1 but the button color do not change. I click again the likes decreases by one and the button color is still gray. I click again THEN the likes increases by 1 and the color changes to PINK. it should change from the first time, right?

Comment: Where are you running this code from ? Could you add some image to your question ? Is the likes button one single image in your view or is it part of some cell ? This might not be the issue of running the lines of code in sequence but with the button configuration perhaps. If you have the repo or a simple way for me to set this up at my end, I can have a better look. Right now, I only gave the solution to show you how to perform some task after the rows have reloaded.